# error while importing pika for python module in windows os

Tags: python, pika, python-pika

When I am  trying to import pika in my python module and it shows error message as **Unresolved import: pika**

```
import pika
```

I am using windows os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Pika was not installed my machine. I used

```
pika-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl to install it.
```

command to install it is

```
python -m pip install pika-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```